# JSON_CONTAINS for multiple attributes on object in array?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json

Currently using MYSQL 5.7, soon to be migrating to 8.0.
We have a json field in our database which has values which look like this:

```
[
  {
     "first_name":"bob",
     "last_name":"lisserman"
  },
  {
     "first_name":"bob",
     "last_name":"rippleman"
  },
  {
     "first_name":"joe",
     "last_name":"roterlam"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to write a query which finds records which contain an object in the array with both "first_name" = "bob" AND "last_name" = "rippleman"

Does `JSON_CONTAINS` support a search like this?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @GMB - Added info on version in description. MYSQL 5.7 now, hoping to move to 8.0 soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [12.17.3 Functions That Search JSON Values :: JSON_CONTAINS(target, candidate[, path])](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html):
>
> ...
>
> - A candidate object is contained in a target object if and only if for each key in the candidate there is a key with the same name in the
>     target and the value associated with the candidate key is contained in
>     the value associated with the target key.
>
> ...

MySQL 5.7 and MySQL 8.0 try:

```sql
SELECT
  `id`,
  `json_field`
FROM
  `tbl_table`
WHERE
  JSON_CONTAINS(`json_field`, '{"first_name": "bob", "last_name": "rippleman"}');
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=aaeaf5cc85ecaf2dbfc87631699fff62).

MySQL 8.0 try:

```sql
SELECT
  `tbl_table`.`id`,
  `tbl_table`.`json_field`
FROM
  `tbl_table`, JSON_TABLE(
    `json_field`,
    '$[*]'
    COLUMNS(
      `first_name` VARCHAR(50) PATH '$.first_name',
      `last_name` VARCHAR(50) PATH '$.last_name'
    )
) `der`
WHERE
  `der`.`first_name` = 'bob' AND
  `der`.`last_name` = 'rippleman';
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8335feb8e9afa0031301290e21f1a01c).